# How do I attach my website icon to metamask signature?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, signature, metamask

I used this tag

```
<link rel ="short icon" type="image/x-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
```

But it doesn't really add the image to my signature message.

Instead of the icon a letter D is displayed at the top of the signature message.

Di is the first letter of my website url.

I have user persoanl signature to generate the signature.

So, is there any way I can add my site icon in place of letter D ?
[image: I want to replace this letter T]

[image: and use thise site icon]